# How to support offline mode in Cordova in Visual studio 2015 project

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am creating a hybrid mobile application on Visual Studio 2015 using Cordova and Ionic.

The app will be used by Agents. They'll visit fields and collect data from users.

The requirement is to allow them to put app in offline mode. When agent chooses to go offline, first the app should call service and store returned data in the storage (encrypted: should we use SQLLite with SQLCiphter?) so that app can function correctly. After this it should go offline.

Agent will start collecting data, the data collected from the users will remain in the device memory (may be in HTML5 localstorage but in encrypted format).

After that agent will choose to go online, on that event the app should send the data to the service. The service will return approve or reject status for each applicant. For rejected application, agent will contact user and will work with her to rectify the error - and again sends data to the service.

I need to know what plugins should I be using for local encrypted storage. The encryption/decryption should be on the go, for example, if user enters details on screen 1 and proceeds to screen 2 the details in screen 1 should be stored in encrypted format, and if he goes back to screen 1 from screen 2 then app should decrypt the local data and should allow to edit.

For local encrypted storage SQLLite with SQLCipher will be a good option?

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us more about your offline functionality: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to save files to use them when offline? Do you want to prevent web service calls when offline? Otherwise noone will be able to help you...

Comment: I updated the question with details, please let me know if more clarification is needed.